# Back reference on multiple join paths

Tags: sqlalchemy

The sqlalchemy docs explain how to handle [multiple join paths](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html). Unfortunately, it doesn't explain how to implement the back reference.

To stick to the example in the docs, I tried

- Simply adding `backref='Customer'` to both relationships. As expected, this fails because it can't add the same backref twice
- Manually adding the relationship on the *Address* side and specifying `back_populates` on *Customer*. This also does not seem to work.

Is it possible to have a shared back reference for both forward references? If yes, how?